# Conditionally match a word using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to replace all words that contain `abc` , but do not contain `KLM` right before `abc`.

For example , `"dasdasKLMabc"` should not be changed, but `"dasabc"` is good to replace, I want to replace `abc` with `rrr`.

Answer (score 3):

sed doesn't seem to support look-behind. but you can do it in perl fairly easy:

```
sorin@sorin:~$ echo -e "llalaabc\nKLMabc" | perl -pe 's/(?<!KLM)abc/rrr/'
llalarrr
KLMabc
sorin@sorin:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU sed does not support look-ahead and look-behind as far as I know. A simple way to solve your problem would be to replace `KLMabc` with some 'unique' string, replace all `abc`s and then replace the unique string back with `KLMabc`

```
sed 's/KLMabc/#####/g' <input_file> | sed 's/abc/rrr/g' | sed 's/#####/KLMabc'
```

or

```
sed 's/KLMabc/#####/g' -e 's/abc/rrr/g' -e 's/#####/KLMabc' <input_file>
```

Comment: Rather than hazard a guess at a 'unique' string use `\n` as this string will never be present in the pattern space (unless added by the user).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [`ssed`](https://launchpad.net/ssed/), you would be able to use a Perl-style [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
ssed -R 's/(?<!KLM)abc/rrr/g' input.txt
```

Example:

```
$ echo "dasdasKLMabc dasabc" | ssed -R 's/(?<!KLM)abc/rrr/g'
dasdasKLMabc dasrrr
```